# Menu in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Menu view

```
<td colspan="3" width="60">
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li ><a href="pages/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/staff">Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/chat">Chat</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/championat">Championat</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

main_view

```
<table width="1100" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
    <?php $this->load->view('header_view'); ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <?php $this->load->view('menu_view'); ?>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"  id="content">
      <?php
        $url = $_GET['pages/'];
        switch($url)
        {
            case "home":
                require("pages/home");
                break;
            case "about":
                require("pages/about");
                break;
        }
      ?>
    </td>
    <?php $this->load->view('rightMenu_view'); ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <?php $this->load->view('footer_view'); ?>
</tr>
```

How to switch the option of menu in 
I try this solution but doesn't work!!!!
Can you help me pliz???
I have also a controller names "page" this controller have methods:home,about,staff,chat,championat
Thx

HELP PLIZZZ!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need the function name of your controller? Try this:

```
echo $this->uri->segment(2); //will give you home/about/staff etc.
```

Read about the [`uri segments`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html) here.

**Edit:**

```
$controller  = $this->uri->segment(1);
$method      = $this->uri->segment(2);
$what_i_need = $controller.'/'.$method;
```

Comment: I need that pages/home,pages/about,pages/staff..etc

Comment: Message: Undefined index: pages/
Where I need to edite this:
$controller  = $this->uri->segment(1);
$method      = $this->uri->segment(2);
$what_i_need = $controller.'/'.$method;

Comment: Where do you want this?

Comment: Like this:
case "home":
                  $pages = $this->uri->segment(1);
                  $home      = $this->uri->segment(2);
                  $what_i_need = $pages.'/'.$home;

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this wrong. Your view should never be making display decisions based on URLs. That is the controller's job. In your `pages` controller, the second part of the URL will be mapped to a function of the same name.  You can then make the decision in the controller of which view to load, and pass it in a data object to your `main_view`.

`pages.php` (Controller):

```
function home()
{
    $data['pageURL'] = 'pages/home';
    $this->load->view('main_view',$data);
}
```

Then in your `main_view.php`:

```
...
<td colspan="2"  id="content">
<?php require($pageURL); ?>
</td>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following

```
$this->data['controller'] = $this->router->fetch_class();
$this->data['action'] = $this->router->fetch_method();
```

This will give controller name and method name. pass this from controller to view.